# How to display the curve with my two differential equations?

Tags: python

Hello i'm trying to implement the euler explicit method with my code.
Here are my two differential equation.
- dSdt = ps*S*(1-((R + S)/K)) - (C * S)
- dRdt = pr*R*(1-((R + S)/K)) - (beta*S*R)

How can i display the curve ?

Thank you for your answers.

```
h = 0.5
t = np.linspace(0, 35, 35)
def S(t):
    if(t <= 0):
        return S0
    else:
        return funcS(t - h) + h * ps*funcS(t - h)*(1-((funcR(t - h) + funcS(t - h))/K)) - (C * funcS(t - h))

def R(t):
    if(t == 0):
        return R0
    else:
        return pr*funcR(t - h)*(1-((funcR(t - h) + funcS(t - h))/K)) - (beta*funcS(t - h)*funcR(t - h))
```

Comment: are you familiar with matplotlib? you can use a plotting library if you want to display your curve.

Comment: i'm not very familiar with matprolib, i tried something like that :

Comment: fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axis_bgcolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.plot(t, funcS(t), 'r', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Sensible')  
ax.plot(t, funcR(t), 'b', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Resistant')

Comment: this looks like it could work too, you will need to call `plt.show()` after those lines since you aren't running this in an interactive environment. see my answer below for a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(t, S(t))          # assuming you want to plot S(t)
plt.show()                 # this will display your figure
```